# How to expand a C++ macro before it is passed as an argument to another macro

Tags: c++

I have this sample C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>

#define TEST( function ) \
    [](){\
        std::cout << function << std::endl;\
    }()

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) { 
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    TEST(__FUNCTION__);
}
```

When I run it I get this output:

```
main
main::<lambda_e118d547a20d031f709c1a0a4ae901df>::operator ()
```

which shows that `__FUNCTION__` is expanded inside the macro TEST

What I'd like though is to be able to expand `__FUNCTION__` before passing it to the macro TEST and get this output:

```
main
main
```

Comment: Forgive me but I must ask, why must `TEST` be a macro?

Comment: @Bathsheba: It doesn't really matter, does it? You get the same result if you expand the macro by hand.

Comment: @TonyK: I'm asking because `__FUNCTION__` is not actually a macro.

Comment: Ady, why do you need this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`__FUNCTION__` is not a macro,** it's a static variable. (See [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html).)

Therefore there is no way to 'expand' it in the context of `main`, if it ends up inside of in a lambda.

---

Making `TEST` a regular function will solve this problem.

Comment: This code is a very simplified version of a quite complex issue I'm trying to address which, due to various constraints, has to be dealt with this way.

Comment: @Ady It boils down to the fact that after macro expansion, `__FUNCTION__` has to end up in the `main` rather than in a lambda. If you tell us more about the problem you're solving, we might be able to give a more specific advice.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I think __FUNCTION__ not being a macro reply answers my question. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I resolved this:

```
#include <iostream>

#define TEST \
    [](const char* function){\
        std::cout << function << std::endl;\
    }(__FUNCTION__)

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) { 
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    TEST;
}
```

The output is now:

```
main
main
```